# How long should it take to rebuild a wheel?

Tags: wheel-building

I'm planning to replace the hub on my front wheel, from a QR to a 20mm.

How much labor, skill, equipment, etc. does that need, and how much time should I expect a pro to charge for, to do the rebuild?

Comment: All mine have cost me nothing, other than a few hour of my time.

Comment: While [we allow localized question](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/107/are-country-specific-questions-too-localized) in the sense of geography, what one would pay for a rebuild is an *extremely* localized question. Closing this question. @Cameron, welcome to the site; please take a look at [this page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and also our FAQ for more information on the types of questions that work well here.

Comment: @Cameron Bain: 2-3 hours of shop time. In Park City, I'd expect 100-150 US dollars. 150 would be on the high side.

Comment: @neilFein: too quick on the trigger there. Could have been edited to something like "How long should it take to build a wheel?" which would allow non localized info to get you local pricing.

Comment: @ChrisW: I didn't edit because now it looks like we closed a legit question. Can it be unclosed?

Comment: Can we downvote @NeilFein? :P

Comment: @zenbike - You can vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Chris: how? @Stephen: if he comments, but give him the benefit of the doubt. Tough job, and he does try to do it well. Feel free to upvote my comments to him though.

Comment: @zenbike - Up there below the OP, under the <wheel-building] tag, where it currently says, "reopen (1)": click on that, to vote to reopen.

Comment: Doesn't show for me. XP requirement? Or cause I'm on mobile layout?

Comment: My main concern is that answers to this question are limited to  what repairs cost in a particular area. It seems more suited to chat or a conventional forum. I closed it *quick* because it'll attract chatty answers like "I paid [price] for my rebuild." Of course, if the community reopens, that's all well and good, but perhaps someone should raise this in chat so we'll have a precedent for similar questions in the future.

Comment: I agree with Neil Fein. This could go on and on. If this question is allowed one could then proceed to ask "...how long should it take..." or "...how much will it cost..." for every single bicycle repair or upgrade. If one intends to pay for a repair, it's easy enough to call around to a few local bike shops for price/time comparisons.

Comment: A quick google search shows at least 5 such shops in the Park City area...

Comment: @zenbike - [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98244) suggests that voting on mobile is supported: on comments - and  [this illustration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98215) suggests that it isn't for questions.

Comment: @zenbike - And [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98215/stack-exchange-mobile-theme-beta-starts-now/98227#98227) - but I guess that support for mobile browsers will increase in future.

Comment: @Chris: Voting for questions and comments works, but the open/close vote doesn't show on mobile. I'm at work now, and it does on the notebook, so it must be a mobile thing.

Comment: @Neil Fein: Isn't that what status point protected  questions are supposed to be for? @ChrisW: Move to chat or Meta for further comments on mobile layout, just to keep the modgods happy :).

Comment: @zebbike - That only protects against <=10 rep users leaving "thanks"-type comments and answers, alas.

Comment: If I were doing my 3rd or 4th wheel in a row I could probably do it in an hour, with another 15-30 minutes spent truing the wheel.  But every time I do it I have to get out the book and study for half an hour, then find all the right tools, make sure I have enough spokes, find the spoke dip, etc.  Then I usually have one or two false starts before I get the lacing right.  For tools you don't need much -- cluster removal tools if rear wheel (not needed if just replacing rim), truing stand, dishing gauge, spoke wrench and/or screwdriver.  And a good book will tell you how to do it.

Comment: Nice edit, @ChrisW, @zenbike! This makes the question much more answerable, have "cast" the final reopen votes.

Comment: Just curious how a shop can survive on charging $30-50 per hour??? Certainly not focusing on wheel work.

Comment: My last wheel build was a rear 700.  Parts were $100 for 38 spokes  (36+2 spares), and $70 for the rim.  The NOS hub I already had.  Lacing was 2 hours of my time, and initial truing another 2 hours where I gave up.  Shop finished the truing for another $10 and a good laugh.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are willing to spend a few hours, it's worth doing yourself.  Depending on the flange size of the new hub, though, you may need to buy new spokes.  You can determine the length of the spokes you will need using a [spoke length calculator](http://www.bikeschool.com/tools/spoke-length-calculator).

You will need a spoke wrench, a flat-head screwdriver, some vaseline, and the use of a truing stand.  Here's what you'll have to do:

1. Remove the tire, innertube, and rim tape from the wheel.
2. Using a spoke wrench, loosen and remove the nipples.
3. If you are using the same spokes, remove the spokes from the old hub.
4. Lace the wheel, making ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN that the valve will be in the right place.  Check out [Sheldon Brown's step-by-step wheelbuilding page](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/wheelbuild.html) for the procedure of lacing a 3x (three-cross) wheel.  You will want to use a little bit of vaseline on the threads of each spoke so you can tighten the nipples more easily.
5. Go to a nearby bicycle cooperative (you can google bicycle co-op near nameofyourtown) to use a truing stand, and use the truing stand to adjust the wheel.  Make sure the wheel is dished properly and that you have proper tension on the spokes.

Because spokes stretch a little and settle in after you start riding, be prepared to true the wheel after the first couple rides.

If you are not interested in making your own wheel, I recommend just buying a new wheel with the hub you want.  It may be cheaper than getting your lbs to rebuild your wheel with your new hub.

Comment: I personally would never reuse the old spokes unless I couldn't get new ones (unless, perhaps, the wheel is nearly new and the reason for rebuilding is not related to stress on the wheel).  Spokes fatigue over time, and one might as well start fresh.

Comment: Daniel: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought that the wheel was new but with the undesired hub, so I addressed it as I did. Now that I see that the question does not mention anything about the age or wear on the current wheel, I realize I should have included that reusing old, used spokes can lead to disaster and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I made a call around to 3 local reputable shops. The time for this job by a pro is estimated at 2 - 3 hours. The labor charges are estimated at $40 to $60. Any parts needed add to the cost. This is localized to Portland, OR where there are numerous bike shops. I'm sure the *price* will vary depending on the location; but the *time* involved should be about the same.

Now, if you do this yourself...the time it will take will depend on your experience...so anywhere from a couple of hours to several hours.

Comment: It should be noted that it's much, much faster to change out a rim than to completely build a new wheel (or rebuild an old one).  The two rims can be clipped/taped together and the spokes transferred one at a time from one rim to the other.

Comment: @Daniel - I was only answering how much time a pro might estimate. Not shortcuts or technique since the question isn't asking for that.

Comment: Yes, but I figured it was relevant to the overall discussion.  Needing to replace a rim is a fairly frequent problem, and, without further info, readers might get the impression that it's as slow/expensive to replace a rim as to rebuild an entire wheel.

Answer (score 1):

> 2-3 hours of shop time. In Park City, I'd expect 100-150 US dollars.
>   150 would be on the high side. – zenbike 15 hours ago

Of course it can be done faster, and likely will be, but this is a standard time to expect. Your shop rates may vary, but the time should be consistent around the globe.

Answer (score 0):

OK not the question as stated but

1. What hub?
   Most newer hubs have [conversion](http://www.notubes.com/20mm-End-Caps-for-330HD-Hub--P838.aspx) kits.
2. Is it cost effective?
   Like a [Stans Crest](http://www.notubes.com/ZTR-Crest-C163.aspx) that is a decent wheel the full wheel with hub is $600 and the rim is $100.  Unless you have a high end rim it is probably not cost effective if you are paying a shop.

Don't mean to advertise Stan's and I am not associated with Stan's.  Just using Stan's as an example.

I just now noticed this is an old question.  I would not even have answered if I had realized that.